# How to add multiple series on a Chart in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, automation, series

I would like to add a chart like the following picture.

[image: Excel Chart]

This chart has 3 series (Black, Red, Blue).

The following is a block of code that creates "one" series on a chart...

```
Excel._Workbook oWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)oSheet.Parent;
Excel._Chart oChart = (Excel._Chart)oWorkbook.Charts.Add(oSheet, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// Y axis data
Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.get_Range(yRange, Type.Missing);

// Creates a chart
oChart.ChartWizard(oRange, chartType, 2, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, title, xAxisTitle, yAxisTitle, Type.Missing);

// Sets X axis category
Excel.Series oSeries = (Excel.Series)oChart.SeriesCollection(1);    
oSeries.XValues = oSheet.get_Range(xRange, Type.Missing);
oChart.Name = chartName;
```

MSDN API is not helpful enough and I can hardly find any tutorial or example on this problem. (Or maybe I am not that good searching them)
It would be appreciated if someone gives me a solution.

Comment: Maybe this gives you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422779/c-excel-working-around-maximum-series-size-on-chart

Comment: Well, the comment on the code block says "...multiple series -- this doesn't work yet". Still I tried modifying some lines, but couldn't figured out. :( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve this issue with very simple solution.
If I set the yRange (oRange) right, "ChartWizard" method automatically creates the graphs.
So instead of range having "A2:A100", "A2:A100,C2:C100" will generates two lines (series) on one chart and also if the data range includes the heading (or series label), the "ChartWizard" will automatically put the series name in the legend.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too Familiar with C# but you could try something along the lines of

```
Excel.Range NewRangeObject = oSheet.get_Range(SecondyRange, Type.Missing);        

oChart.NewSeries
oChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "New Series"
oChart.SeriesCollection(2).Value = NewRangeObject
```

To be clear I am kind of guessing based on how the VBA code would look.

A higher level solution is to record a macro in excel directly of setting up the chart exactly the way you want.... then port the Code over to C#. It seems that most of the commands are similiar but wrapped in a slightly different snytax.