# Create a chart with one x-axis and two y-axes

Tags: c#, excel

I have to create a chart with one x axis and two y axis in Interop Excel through C#. My data looks like:

```
Month   Count1  Count2
Jan     229       170
Feb     204        53
Mar     292       106
Apr     513        64
May     592       115
Jun     644       198
Jul     691       182
Aug     407         8
Sep     127        18
Oct      36         8
Nov      76
```

I want to create a graph like this.
[image: graph]

I am able to create graph for count1 column but not getting how to add another y axis. My code:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects chartObjs = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject graphChart = chartObjs.Add(80, 2380, 600, 220);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart chart = graphChart.Chart;
        chart.HasLegend = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xValues = xlWorkSheet1.Range["A1", "A12"];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range yValues = xlWorkSheet1.Range["B1", "B12"];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = chart.HasLegend();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
        series.XValues = xValues;
        series.Values = yValues;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple series on a Chart in Excel using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180608/how-to-add-multiple-series-on-a-chart-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi pnuts, Yeah I want to draw a chart, just like the chart I have displayed above. Could you please help

Comment: Thanks Niraj, The link was useful and I got the expected output.