# Working Around Maximum Series Size on Chart

Tags: excel

I would like to take advantage of the following posting:

[C#/Excel: Working Around Maximum Series Size On Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422779/c-excel-working-around-maximum-series-size-on-chart/30181213#30181213)

Was wondering if someone can include the steps to actually running this macro and producing graph? I opened developer/Visual basic, selected my sheet (where my long column of data resides). Pasted Vincent's code into code window. Guess I should not be surprised that VBA is not recognizing C code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Excel uses VBA - that code should be relatively straightforward to translate: try it out.

Comment: Thanks Tim, per your suggestion I may try to translate it but it sure seemed like the previous poster was using C# with Excel. Is Excel running on Windows an insufficient environment for C#/Excel?

Comment: Your question mentions using VBA.  Maybe you can clarify your terminology a bit: there's a world of difference between VBA and VB.net, and then some between those two and C#.

Comment: The VBA that I am referring to is that provided by Excel as an Add-in (Analysis TookPak - VBA). The charting solution provided by Vincent was coded in C#. Just wondering if this solution can be used running Excel directly, or if it involves some other environment such as Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot run C# code directly from Excel workbook (as you can VBA code).
You can do the reverse: access Excel workbook from C# code (i.e. from Microsoft Visual Studio).